# ANCOVA, checking homogeneity of slopes assumptions

Tags: regression-coefficients, assumptions, ancova

I would like to do an ANCOVA on a set of 2 continuous data set (before and after pill) and one factor with 3 levels (3 pills) Here is the graph of before pill vs after pill with pill taken in colour:.[image: Here is the graph of before pill vs after pill with pill taken in colour]

I would like to know how to evaluate the equality of regression slopes for each pill.

I was thinking of an ANOVA like test, which is for equality of means, but here for the slopes, that takes into account variance.

I saw this other option: [Testing equality of coefficients from two different regressions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93540/testing-equality-of-coefficients-from-two-different-regressions), however I would be forced to make a pairwise analysis, and n the case where I have 1000 pills, might not be efficient.

Is there such a test? and how would it be implemented in r?

Answer (score 2):

I can tell from inspection that the slopes are not significantly different but the typical way to test for differences is with the pretest x trmt interaction.  Most software allows you to specify trmt as a categorical variable and lets you include pretest x trmt in the model (along with pretest and trmt of course). The old way to do it is with dummy variables.

Comment: +1 The suggestion to test the interaction between pretest and tmt is exactly right.