# How to run simultaneous quantile regressions under different if statements ? (Stata 14.0)

Tags: stata

I am new on this blog. 
Data :

```
weight month
127     3
105     2
96      4
117     4
97      3
148     3
135     1
117     3
131     2
100     3
133     4
105     4
118     3
109     4
138     3
129     2
120     2
139     3
120     4
103     1
133     3
98      1
133     1
138     4
149     1
124     4
125     3
127     3
149     2
142     2
103     1
113     4
141     4
124     3
102     2
114     1
99      4
114     3
116     4
133     4
104     3
149     1
112     3
123     3
135     3
106     2
97      1
125     1
142     3
```

I want to simultaneously 4 quantile regressions under different conditions (for the same sample).

```
qreg (weight if month ==1, quantile(0.75)) ///
    (weight if month ==2, quantile(0.75)) ///
    (weight if month ==3, quantile(0.75)) ///
    (weight if month ==4, quantile(0.75))
```

Error message

```
parentheses unbalanced
r(132);
`
```

I need to run these regressions simultaneously for statistical tests.

Otherwise, to test the inequality of my quantiles, is it better to perform this ? according to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93540/testing-equality-of-coefficients-from-two-different-regressions)

```
qreg weight if month ==1, quantile(.75) 
 qreg weight if month ==2, quantile(.75)
```

and then building a Z test based on the coefficients (`_b[cons]`) of both regressions and their standard errors? 
I guess, this will follow a the critical values of Z table?

Comment: This is illegal syntax for `qreg` and does not seem to correspond to your stated goal, as it would run the same model for each month separately.

Comment: by running each month separately, could I still perform statistical test on the 75th quantiles of each month?  e.g. 75thpct (month==2) <= 75th pct (month==1) ?

Comment: This seems just about on-topic here as there is a query at its heart about the appropriate model. But a question about why code fails is usually off-topic here.

Comment: This really isn't a blog!

Comment: What does plotting (as mentioned in the title) have to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is not panel data, you could do something like this:

```
qreg weight i.month, quantile(0.75)
margins month
marginsplot
margins month, pwcompare
```

One-sided tests are a bit trickier.

Comment: How would your code change if this is panel data?

Comment: You would need to adjust that the observations are no longer independent. Clustered standard errors won't work with `qreg`, but there may be a way to block bootstrap the procedure, though that can't be done with the data as it is now.

Comment: Please, see the edit of my post

Comment: `suest` will not work with `qreg`, so there is no way to combine the 4 quantile regressions constants.