# Testing equality of two coefficients of two separate regressions in R

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing

I run the following regressions:

```
Y_1 ~ c_1 + b_1*X
Y_2 ~ c_2 + b_2*X
```

and I get two estimates for b_1 and b_2. What is the appropiate statistic to test if `b_1 <= b_2` and is there a function for that in R?

Comment: It seems that the appropriate procedure can be found here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93540/testing-equality-of-coefficients-from-two-different-regressions

Comment: Do the "$X$" in the two regressions have any data in common?  Are the regressions performed using the same technique?  In brief, is there any way in which the estimates of the $b_i$ might be statistically related or not?

Comment: The "$X$" are identical and both are linear regressions, i.e. use OLS.

Comment: Would it be fair to understand this situation as consisting of two replications of the same experiment, then?  $X$ would represent the fixed variables and the responses would be the two vectors $Y_1,Y_2.$

Comment: Yes, exactly. The hypothesis could be for example: Doing sport in the morning ($X$) leads to a greater effect on productivity in the morning ($Y1$) than in the afternoon ($Y2$), i.e. ($b1 > b2$).

Comment: Is there a reason you are not fitting these data with a single model?  You simply would make the morning/afternoon distinction one of the variables in the model matrix.  That would reduce your question to testing the afternoon vs. morning effect, which is routine.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your procedure and implemented it with the systemfit package in R. Here is my code:

eq1 <- Y1 ~ X
eq2 <- Y2 ~ X
system <- list( morning = eq1 , afternoon = eq2)

## OLS estimation
fitols <- systemfit( system, data = data)
print(fitols)

# The correct test 
linearHypothesis(fitols, "morning_X - afternoon_X = 0" )

Comment: It's unclear what you might need a package for.  Doesn't base `R` accomplish this with `summary(lm(c(Y1,Y2) ~ c(X,X) + factor(rep(0:1, each=length(X)))))`?