# Testing equality of difference in coefficients from four regressions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference

This question is a follow-up/extension to this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93540/testing-equality-of-coefficients-from-two-different-regressions).

Suppose I have four regressions.

$y_i=x_i\beta_i+\epsilon_i,\quad i=1,2,3,4$

I want to test whether $(\beta_1-\beta_2)-(\beta_3-\beta_4)>0$. Can I use the following z-test?

$z=\frac{(\beta_1-\beta_2)-(\beta_3-\beta_4)}{\sqrt{SE\beta_1^2+SE\beta_2^2+SE\beta_3^2+SE\beta_4^2}}$.

Many thanks!

Comment: Are the responses in the four regressions independent?

Comment: @whuber yes they are.

Comment: Please edit your question to add this essential information.