# Compare regression coefficients across two (or more) svyglm() models

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, survey

The question I have is related to [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93540/testing-equality-of-coefficients-from-two-different-regressions), but slightly more specific.

Suppose I use data from a large-scale educational assessment to investigate how students' proficiency in math depends on their background characteristic, such as gender and socioeconomic status. The data come from a study in which a low-stakes test was used to capture students' math proficiency. Now, performance on a low-stakes test has been shown to depend on both cognitive and non-cognitive factors, the example of the latter being conscientiousness. Hence, I want to include some proxy for non-cognitive skills in my analysis. Specifically, I want to estimate two models:

`Model 1: math ~ gender + ses`

and

`Model 2: math ~ gender + ses + conscientiousness`

Let's say I am interested in how the coefficient for gender differs across these two models. That is, if `b1` is the estimate of the coefficient in Model 1, and `b2` is the estimate of the coefficient in Model 2, I am interested in whether the difference `b1 - b2` is statistically significantly different from 0. To answer this question, I need a standard error for the difference. This amounts to calculating the variance of `b1 - b2` which is equal to `Var(b1) + Var(b2) - 2 * Cov(b1, b2)`. The tricky part here is `Cov(b1, b2)`, as the variances are obtained easily.

A simple method of estimating the covariance was proposed by [Clogg et al. (1995)](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/230638). [Mize et al. (2019)](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/0081175019852763) suggested that the covariance term can be estimated using seemingly unrelated regression. I am not sure how to apply these method to my problem, given that:

1. the data I use come from a complex, multi-stage clustered sample. One has to apply survey weights and a set of replicate weights to obtain correct points estimates and standard errors. Specifically, to fit the regression models, I use `survey::svyglm()` with a `survey::svrepdesign()` survey design object.
2. proficiency in math is not represented by a single score but by a set of 10 plausible values. After the models for each plausible values are estimated separately, I aggregate the results using Rubin's aggregation rules.

In light of these complexities, how can I test the difference `b1 - b2` for significance?