# How can I compute the standard error of the Wald estimator?

Tags: econometrics, standard-error, causality, instrumental-variables

According to Cameron and Trivedi *Microeconometrics* 2006, page 98-99, the Wald estimator can be written :

$$
\widehat{\beta}_{Wald} = \frac{(\bar{y_1} - \bar{y_0})}{(\bar{x_1} - \bar{x_0})}
$$

with :

- $\bar{y_1}$ : the mean of y for individuals with Z = 1
- $\bar{y_0}$ : the mean of y for individuals with Z = 0
- $\bar{x_1}$ : the mean of x for individuals with Z = 1
- $\bar{x_0}$ : the mean of x for individuals with Z = 0

I'm in a special case where $y_i$ is a dichotomic variable. I would like to know if there is a formula to compute the standard error in this simple case.

PS : I know there is a similar question ([questions60893](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60893/standard-error-of-the-quotient-of-two-estimates-wald-estimators-using-the-delt)), but my question is really about the algebra and how to compute it knowing only $\bar{y_1}$, $\bar{y_0}$, $\bar{x_1}$, $\bar{x_0}$, $N_1$ the number of people with $Z=1$ and $N_0$ the number of people with $Z=0$, not about the stata command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Standard error of the quotient of two estimates (Wald estimators) using the delta method](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60893/standard-error-of-the-quotient-of-two-estimates-wald-estimators-using-the-delt)

Comment: I don't think so. See my PS.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification, I think [soakely's comment](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/60903/9866) referring to Fieller could be a helpful but the reference to the original Wald paper is certainly interesting.

Comment: The Wald estimator is equivalent to the 2SLS (with binary endogeneous and binary instrument). You could just use a 2SLS and its standard errors?

Comment: I know but I don't have access to the raw data. I only have aggregate quantities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my answer to my question. I hope there is no mistake in calculus.

We have :

- $y_{1,i}$ a dichotomous random variable following a Bernouilli distribution with parameter $\mu_{y_1}$
- $y_{0,i}$ a dichotomous random variable following a Bernouilli distribution with parameter $\mu_{y_0}$
- $x_{1,i}$ a dichotomous random variable following a Bernouilli distribution with parameter $\mu_{x_1}$
- $x_{0,i}$ a dichotomous random variable following a Bernouilli distribution with parameter $\mu_{x_0}$

The Wald estimator is defined as :

$$
\beta_{Wald} = \frac{\mu_{y_1} - \mu_{y_0}}{\mu_{x_1} - \mu_{x_0}}
$$

This can be estimated using the plug-in estimator :

$$
\widehat{\beta_{Wald}} = \frac{\bar{y_1} - \bar{y_0}}{\bar{x_1} - \bar{x_0}}
$$

I want to know the distribution of $\widehat{\beta_{Wald}}$. Since $\bar{y_1} - \bar{y_0}$ and $\bar{x_1} - \bar{x_0}$ converge to a normal distribution, I know that I can derive the distribution of $\widehat{\beta_{Wald}}$ using the Delta method (See Larry Wasserman, *All of Statistics : A Concise Course in Statistical Inference*, Springer, coll. « Springer Texts in Statistics », 2004, page 79).

I define two new variables :

- $U = \bar{y_1} - \bar{y_0}$
- $V = \bar{X_1} - \bar{X_0}$

I know that :

- $U \xrightarrow{L}\, \mathcal{N}(\mu_U, \sigma^2_U)$
- $V \xrightarrow{L}\, \mathcal{N}(\mu_V, \sigma^2_V)$

I define the function $g(U,V) = U/V$. According to the Delta method, I know that :

$$
g(U,V) \xrightarrow{L}\, \mathcal{N}\left(g(\mu_U, \mu_V), Dg(\mu_U, \mu_V)^T\Sigma Dg(\mu_U, \mu_V)\right)
$$

with $Dg(\mu_U, \mu_V)$ the Jacobian matrix of function `g` and $\Sigma$ the variance-covariance matrix of vector $(U,V)$.

So I compute the Jacobian :

$$Dg \left( \begin{array}{c} \mu_U \\ \mu_V \end{array} \right) = \left(\begin{array}{rcl} \frac{1}{\mu_V} \\ \frac{-\mu_U}{\mu_V^2} \end{array} \right)  $$

and I have the variance-covariance matrix :

$$
\Sigma = \left( \begin{array}{cc} \sigma^2_U & \sigma_{U,V} \\ \sigma_{U,V} & \sigma^2_V \end{array} \right)
$$

So the variance of $g(U/V)$ is :

$$
Dg(\mu_U, \mu_V)^T \Sigma Dg(\mu_U, \mu_V) =
 \frac{\sigma^2_U}{\mu_V^2} - 2  \frac{\mu_U}{\mu_V^3}  \sigma_{U,V} + \frac{\mu_U^2}{\mu_V^4} \sigma^2_V
$$

In this case, since $y_i$ follow a Bernouilli distribution, its variance is just $\mu_{y_i} (1-\mu_{y_i})$ and can be estimated using the plug-in estimator as $\bar{y_i} (1-\bar{y_i})$. Therefore I can estimate the following quantities :

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\sigma^2_U & = & V(\bar{y_1} - \bar{y_0})\\
            & = & V(\bar{y_1}) +  V(\bar{y_0})
            & = & \frac{1}{N_1} \bar{y_1} (1 - \bar{y_1}) + \frac{1}{N_0} \bar{y_0} (1 - \bar{y_0})
\end{eqnarray}
$$

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\sigma^2_V & = & V(\bar{x_1} - \bar{x_0})\\
            & = & V(\bar{x_1}) +  V(\bar{x_0})
            & = & \frac{1}{N_1} \bar{x_1} (1 - \bar{x_1}) + \frac{1}{N_0} \bar{x_0} (1 - \bar{x_0})
\end{eqnarray}
$$

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\sigma_{U,V} & = & cov(\bar{y_1} - \bar{y_0}, \bar{x_1} - \bar{x_0})\\
& = & \beta_1 V(\bar{x_1}) + \beta_1 V(\bar{x_0})\\
& = & \beta_1 \left( \frac{1}{N_1} \bar{x_1} (1 - \bar{x_1}) + \frac{1}{N_0} (\bar{x_0} (1-\bar{x_0}))\right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

So I can have sample estimates of all quantities in the equation   $\frac{\sigma^2_U}{\mu_V^2} - 2  \frac{\mu_U}{\mu_V^3}  \sigma_{U,V} + \frac{\mu_U^2}{\mu_V^4} \sigma^2_V$. Therefore I can get the variance of my Wald estimator and compute my standard error !

Answer (score 2):

Consider pages 287 - 290 in the original [Wald(1940)](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177731868) paper. It walks you through the derivation of the variance.

Comment: I think you meant Wald (1940). :-)

Comment: @tchakravarty, excellent catch. Who knew Wald could write papers 40 years after his death

Answer (score 2):

For future readers: the $\beta_1$ in @MichaelChirico's post is $\beta_\mathrm{wald}$ (the average treatment effect, in usual use), and the covariance formula follows from $E[Y|X] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X$ without loss of generality (since X is binary).

(Apologies for the extra answer; I have insufficient reputation to comment)