# Confidence intervals for percentage share of multiple response

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, sample

If I have a sample of 100, who give responses to a set of multiple response variables, say for example, the brands they have purchased in the last 12 months.

How can I calculate the confidence intervals around the percentage for the share of all purchases for a particular brand?

I can use standard confidence interval formula for CI around "%" but can the same be said for CI around "Share %" as displayed below?

```
-----------------------------------
Brand   |  N   |   %   | Share %
-----------------------------------

Brand1  |  20  |  20%  |  9%

Brand2  |  40  |  40%  | 19%

Brand3  |  45  |  45%  | 21%

Brand4  |  35  |  35%  | 16%

Brand5  |  75  |  70%  | 35%
-----------------------------------
Total   | 215  |       | 100%
-----------------------------------
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not 100% confident but I would personally use the sum of gaussian and ratio of gaussian. 
Let S1 the variable which represents Share1.
S1=X1/(X1+X2+X3+X4+X5) where Xi are independent gaussian distributions which represents each Brand.
X1+X2+X3+X4+X5 behaves like a gaussian distribution with (using probabilities, not %) :

- A standard error of sqrt(s1²+s2²+s3²+s4²+s5²), where si=sqrt(pi*(1-pi)/N). For example : s1=sqrt(0.6*(0.4)/100)=0.049
- A mean of p1+p2+p3+p4+p5=2.15

Once it's computed, the last step is to compute the confidence interval of a ratio of normal distributions. This question seems to have been properly answered there [How to compute the confidence interval of the ratio of two normal means](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16349/how-to-compute-the-confidence-interval-of-the-ratio-of-two-normal-means) an online calculator has been put in place by the first respondent using Fieller's method.