# How to compute the confidence interval of the difference of two normal means

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, mean

Let $X_1,\ldots ,X_N,i=1,\ldots,N$ i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(\mu_X,\sigma_1^2)$ distributed random variables and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_N,i=1,\ldots,N$ i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(\mu_Y,\sigma_2^2)$ distributed random variables. Furthermore, let $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,\ldots,X_N)$ be independent from $\mathbf{Y}=(Y_1,\ldots,Y_N)$.

Find a confidence interval of minimal length for $\mu_X-\mu_Y$ to the level $1-\alpha$.

---

**My approach:** It seems that the statistical model to be considered here is the product model with family of probability measures $\mathcal{N}(\mu_X,\sigma_1^2)^{\otimes N}\otimes\mathcal{N}(\mu_Y,\sigma_2^2)^{\otimes N}$ and that the confidence interval is to be constructed wrt. this family of measures. I'm not sure how to continue from here and the case of [ratios of two means](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16349/how-to-compute-the-confidence-interval-of-the-ratio-of-two-normal-means) seems to be quite different.

How do I continue?

**EDIT:** By one of the comments below, I have now done the following: Observe that $\bar{X}-\bar{Y} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_X-\mu_Y,\sigma^2)$, with $\sigma^2$ having some ancillary and unknown (but expressible in terms of $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$) value. This means that we are now dealing with the problem of finding a confidence interval for the normal distribution in the case of unknown mean and unknown variance and thus

$C(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=(\bar{X} -t^*\sqrt{s^2/N},\bar{X} +t^*\sqrt{s^2/N})$,

with $t^*$ the $1-\alpha/2$ quantile of the $t_{N-1}$ distribution and $s^2$ the unbiased sample variance. I would very much appreciate any feedback regarding the correctness of this.

Comment: Start by expressing the question in terms of the distribution of $\bar X - \bar Y,$ which reduces it to a (familiar) univariate problem.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the help, I assume you mean the respective sample means by $\bar{X},\bar{Y}$ ?

Comment: If you look at textbook discussions for the two-sample Welch t tests, you may find formulas for CIs for $\mu_1-\mu_2.$ I mention the Welch test because variances are unknown and different.

Answer (score 2):

Comment continued: In case you want to check your answer against computer printout for a Welch t test in R, here are fictitious data and relevant computer printout.

```
set.seed(2021)
x1 = rnorm(30, 50, 7)
summary(x1);  length(x1);  sd(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  36.54   47.66   51.10   51.06   57.38   62.11 
[1] 30
[1] 7.651895

x2 = rnorm(30, 40, 5)
summary(x2);  length(x2);  sd(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  28.72   33.06   38.22   38.25   41.32   50.60 
[1] 30
[1] 5.506919

t.test(x1, x2)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = 7.4401, df = 52.686, p-value = 9.136e-10
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:                ## <----
  9.353202 16.258810
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 51.05916  38.25315
```